# Calling a list within an SQL query

Tags: sql, vb.net

I have a select statement that involves a "IN" clause:

```
SELECT *
FROM [database]
WHERE [variablename] IN (1..2..3..4..)
```

Some of my variables are a letter followed by a number in sequential order. For example, V1, V2, V3....V30.

I would like to avoid typing every variable within the statement, is there a way to create an array or list that could store those 30 variables for me and then call them in the query? Or generate the variables by range?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/337704/parameterize-a-sql-in-clause?rq=1

Comment: This helps partially, the second part though--is there a way to create a list of variables (from V1 to V30), for example, without typing thirty completely out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the values in a table (could be a temp table) and join on that table.

```
declare @i int = 0

while  @i < 30
begin 
    insert into tableName (columnName)
    select 'V' + cast(@i as varchar)
    select @i = @i + 1
end

select  *
from    [database] a inner join [database] b on a.columnName = b.columnName
```

Comment: Which would be the same as me manually typing them in the query, I'm trying to avoid that. I have ten different categories (A-J) with a numeric range of 1-30, that's 300 entries into a temp table!

Comment: See my edit - are the values just 1-30 or do they change depending on some situation?

Comment: Yes, this is perfection. Thank you so much!